XML SiteMap Show Path to Files
I am currently using the xml Sitemap module. I am trying to add the path to files in the sitemap xml. At the moment, it just shows the location of the content type, priority and the changeFreq. Is there a way to leverage xml to add path to the files related to those pages? in this situation, i'm looking for the pdf and excel files.

update: i have created a module

This looks like a feature request on the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap/issues/1047178. You would have to find, adapt, or write a module.

Instead of updating this post, add an answer instead. Include details about your module which would benefit the community.
